# Invoke-WebRequest - getting next URI after login (referer?)

Tags: powershell

the first part login to a device with a local webserver as config/monitor tool has been done (I thought).

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://$server" -SessionVariable sv -UseDefaultCredentials -Method Default 

$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.Fields['user'] = 'username'
$form.Fields['pwd'] = 'pw'        #$form.Action is the right one as returned in the form
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://$server" + $form.Action)  -WebSession $sv -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields -TimeoutSec 20
```

Now the problem  ;o)

Doing logging in manually on the webpage, leads to another URL with a dynamic session ID, like this:

`http://$server/xyz.asp;session_id=7a7ff613d48ac87927edf66a356e90e1`

In monitoring tools I see the new URL is coming back and gets used by the browser but I have no clue how to "catch" the new URL to access the next page in the script. 
The content of the response of the second request is still the one from the login page, so I guess the login is not so successfull as the returned StatusCode/Description says.

Any suggestions welcome!
Thx & have a nice day!

---

first result for $r:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : Ok
Content           : <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>Login Page</title>
                    <!--[if lt IE 7.]>
                    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/pngfix.js"></script>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/md5.js"></script>
                    <script t...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Connection: close
                    Cache-Control: no-cache
                    Content-Type: text/html
                    Date: Sun, 18 Nov 2018 21:41:16 GMT
                    Expires: 0
                    Server: httpd

                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>Login Pag...
Forms             : {frm}
Headers           : {[Pragma, no-cache], [Connection, close], [Cache-Control, no-cache], [Content-Type, text/html]...}
Images            : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG style="POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: -1" src="/image/pg.jpg" width="100%">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; style=POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: -1; 
                    src=/image/pg.jpg; width=100%}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG src="/image/cisco_logo_about.png">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; src=/image/cisco_logo_about.png}, @{innerHTML=; 
                    innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG src="/image/ContextMessageArrow_DownT.gif">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; src=/image/ContextMessageArrow_DownT.gif}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG 
                    id=log class=LOGINIMG style="DISPLAY: none" src="/image/login_progress.gif">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; id=log; class=LOGINIMG; style=DISPLAY: none; src=/image/login_progress.gif}}
InputFields       : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=hidden name=submit_button>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; name=submit_button}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT 
                    type=hidden name=keep_name>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; name=keep_name}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=hidden value=1 name=enc>; outerText=; 
                    tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; value=1; name=enc}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=input name=user>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=input; name=user}...}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 5800
```

SessionVariable:

```
Id     : frm
Method : post
Action : /login.cgi
Fields : {[submit_button, ], [keep_name, ], [enc, 1], [user, ]...}
```

second Invoke:

```
# here I'm not sure, the "enc" field is 1 when I read it (don't know if it's read-only)
# and I also tried a secure string for "pwd" but it didn't work either
# so I tried this with "pwd" as simple string and "enc"=0
$form.Fields['user'] = '<user>'        
$form.Fields['pwd'] = '<pw>'       
$form.Fields['enc'] = '0'
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("http://$server" + $form.Action)  -WebSession $sv -Method $form.Method -Body $form.Fields -TimeoutSec 20 -Debug
```

debug output:

```
VERBOSE: POST http://10.122.154.34/login.cgi with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received -1-byte response of content type text/html
# a 1-byte response doesn't look like it worked as expected, right?
```

second result for $r:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : Ok
Content           : <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>Login Page</title>
                    <!--[if lt IE 7.]>
                    <script defer type="text/javascript" src="/pngfix.js"></script>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="/md5.js"></script>
                    <script t...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Connection: close
                    Cache-Control: no-cache
                    Content-Type: text/html
                    Date: Sun, 18 Nov 2018 21:43:34 GMT
                    Expires: 0
                    Server: httpd

                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <title>Login Pag...
Forms             : {frm}
Headers           : {[Pragma, no-cache], [Connection, close], [Cache-Control, no-cache], [Content-Type, text/html]...}
Images            : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG style="POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: -1" src="/image/pg.jpg" width="100%">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; style=POSITION: absolute; Z-INDEX: -1; 
                    src=/image/pg.jpg; width=100%}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG src="/image/cisco_logo_about.png">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; src=/image/cisco_logo_about.png}, @{innerHTML=; 
                    innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG src="/image/ContextMessageArrow_DownT.gif">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; src=/image/ContextMessageArrow_DownT.gif}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<IMG 
                    id=log class=LOGINIMG style="DISPLAY: none" src="/image/login_progress.gif">; outerText=; tagName=IMG; id=log; class=LOGINIMG; style=DISPLAY: none; src=/image/login_progress.gif}}
InputFields       : {@{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=hidden name=submit_button>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; name=submit_button}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT 
                    type=hidden name=keep_name>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; name=keep_name}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=hidden value=1 name=enc>; outerText=; 
                    tagName=INPUT; type=hidden; value=1; name=enc}, @{innerHTML=; innerText=; outerHTML=<INPUT type=input name=user>; outerText=; tagName=INPUT; type=input; name=user}...}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 5800
```

same answer except the date...

---

encrypted string using web-UI:
0fa58742e186c8e5ce52ba133f8714cb

encrypted string from powershell:
01000000d08c9ddf0115d1118c7a00c04fc297eb010000004beb616727b69b4e8264e7cc798eb93d0000000002000000000003660000c0000000100000003ab6ebeb97f783cb9b5a49187ddf72600000000004800000a000000010000
0008df253a8f5995d2dc9b00e5efb7f878510000000fe9616971b02305ee332dd9c3bf6b620140000006809524b3f5eba666022bb70f1eebcea43b57e0b

Comment: What does the response from the new value of `$r` look like?

Comment: I updated the original post

Comment: So once the page updates within the COM object of your IE, the URL does change, yes? I see the InnerHTML property seems to stay blank, but is there any other property you can grab something from once the authentication completes and assigns that dynamic ID?

Comment: will check @ end of week, just "on the road", thx a lot for helping!

Comment: no, nothing to grab, but I think (after I used fiddler) I'm closer to the problem itself...it seems that I'm just using the wrong encryption for the PW

Comment: I cannot switch to "enc=0" so I have to send a encrypted pw ...but ... if I use the powershell technique to ask for a pw (read-host -assecurestring)  store it and bring it back to an encrypted string than I get a huge string which doesn't work, what I get when I'm typing the pw in the web-UI is much shorter, so I think the encryption method is different, but I cannot find anything about it yet; original post edited...

Comment: Cheers Mathias. This tutorial will show you some steps you can use client side with fiddler to at least see what choices the server makes for the handshakes - https://textslashplain.com/2015/10/12/viewing-https-handshakes-in-fiddler/  Hope that helps. I'm still watching your post, curious what you end up landing with

Comment: THX! And have a great weekend!  :o)

Comment: Hi, you won't believe how my "quick & dirty" solution looks like (me either, by the way), but I have no time to dig deeper, maybe after xmas...
I'm just using the already encrypted password (from fiddler) in the script to "logon" via script and get finally the response wanted; okay for me, because in the response is the sessionkey I need to GET the sub page from which I need to read some status values for our asset management...so.....not really solved, but "worked around"...   if I get some time the "correct" way to do it, I'll let you know   ;o)

Comment: Cheers Mathias!